# Help golfing MIPS assembly

Tags: code-golf, tips, assembly

I want to write 7 assembly instructions (28 bytes) that runs a logical equivalent of this C snippet:

```
c = a + b + 6;
while (c > 5) {
  c = c - a;
  b = b + 1;
}
```

However, there are restrictions to the allowed instructions:

```
add, addi, sub, subi, slt, slti, bne
```

`a`, `b`, and `c` are located in registers `$t0`, `$t1`, and `$s0` respectively. Assume they are declared as signed 32 bit integers. You may use other registers as necessary but you may not assume an initial value for any registers except `$0` which is wired to ground (always 0, even if assigned to).

The best attempt to date is thanks to @Smac89 with the following assembly:

```
      addi $s1, $t0, 6     # d = a + 6
      add $s0, $s1, $t1    # c = d + b
loop: slti $t2, $s0, 6     # f = (c < 6) 
      bne $t2, $0, exit    # (c < 6) ? exit
      sub $s0, $s0, $t0    # c = c - a;
      addi $t1, $t1, 1     # b = b + 1;
      bne $s1, $t0, loop   # (d != a) ? loop; always true
exit:
```

Comment: I don't understand, your goal is to do it in 7 instructions, and you post an example that solves it in 7 instructions. What is missing?

Comment: The label is on the 8th instruction, which feels kind of "cheaty." I'd like a more definitive way of doing it in exactly 7 lines (or less if you're feeling Godly).

Comment: Labels are not instructions.